# Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2. due to firewall

Tags: android, gson

I am have trouble implement gson in my project because firewall blocked google and its related servers.But I have gson-2.8.2.jar in my local drive under /home/android-studio3/lib how do I include that in my Android Studio projects?

Step by step guide only please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-Put the jar file in your project directory

2-open your project on android studio

3-locate the jar file in your project in android studio

4-right click and add library

5-enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to just right click the Jar in android studio and select add as library